# componentDidMount not being called after goBack navigation call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I've set up a StackNavigator which will fire a redux action to fetch data on `componentDidMount`, after navigating to another screen and going back to the previous screen, `componentDidMount` is no longer firing and I'm presented with a white screen. I've tried to reset the StackNavigator using `StackActions.reset` but that just leads to my other screens not mounting as well and in turn presenting an empty screen. Is there a way to force `componentDidMount` after `this.props.navigation.goBack()`?

**Go Back Function**

```
_goBack = () => {
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
};
```

**Navigation function to new screen**

```
_showQuest = (questId, questTitle ) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("Quest", {
    questId,
    questTitle,
  });
};
```

Edit :
Hi , I'm still stuck on this matter and was wondering if the SO Community has a solution to force componentDidMount to be called after Navigation.goBack() is called or rather how to Unmount the component after this.props.navigation.navigate is called

Comment: How are you rendering your components? It might be that your other component is not actually unmounted when the navigation changes, and therefor `componentDidMount` will not be called again when you go back.

Comment: After navigating to a new screen, `componentDidMount` will be called the first time  and after going back to the previous screen, it is no longer called. How do you forcefully unmount the screen after navigating to a new screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `didFocus` event listener didn't work for me.

I found a different listener called `focus` which finally worked!

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        // call your refresh method here
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the event listener
    if (this.focusListener != null && this.focusListener.remove) {
        this.focusListener.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The components are not removed when the navigation changes, so `componentDidMount` will only be called the first time it is rendered.

You could use [this alternative approach](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/3345) instead:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFocused: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.subs = [
      this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => this.setState({ isFocused: true })),
      this.props.navigation.addListener("willBlur", () => this.setState({ isFocused: false }))
    ];
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.remove());
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isFocused) {
      return null;
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I recently migrated over from react-native router flux and i'm confused or rather not sure how to implement this approach. would isFocused be the boolean flag to trigger the redux action to fetch the data or navigate to a new screen?

Comment: @AshRhazaly No worries. It's just an example, you don't have to use `isFocused` if you don't want to. The point is just that the `didFocus` and `willBlur` events can be seen as the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` hooks in this case, since the component will never really be mounted/unmounted after the initial mount.

Comment: Do you have a working snack where I can see this implementation? I'm not fully sure how to go about this approach

Comment: @AshRhazaly Sorry, I have no real experience with it myself. I only know what's [written about it in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle).